# The difference between a company and a firm

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In a very famous tv show we talk about a `firm` and in other tv show we talk about `company`

I want to know the main difference between them.

Comment: Both are businesses. Do you mean an agricultural farm or some other kind of 'farm', such as a 'server farm', or a 'puppy farm'?

Comment: @Mick to be honnest with you the first time i heard the word `Farm` was in a very famous tv show that talk about loyers

Comment: Do you perhaps mean *firm* rather than *farm*?

Comment: @StoneyB yes please make an edit because it's your proposition

Comment: No, it's up to *you* to make your question meaningful.

Comment: Again, both are businesses. The term *firm* is very generic and can mean almost anything. The term *company* is a little more specific since a *company* usually has more than one owner (shareholder).

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [What is the difference between a company, organisation, industry, firm, corporation and business?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/61071/)

Comment: Please indicate how you have used a dictionary to try to answer this question yourself.